# How to get n number of vehicles for x sec of simulation using SUMO randomTrips script?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using Veins simulator, for creating cars with path I am using the following commands:

```
python c:/DLR/Sumo/tools/randomTrips.py -n test.net.xml -e 1200 -l
python c:/DLR/Sumo/tools/randomTrips.py -n test.net.xml -r test.rou.xml -e 1200 -l
```

This command generated 1200 vehicles for 1200 sec of simulation but I want to generated 1200 vehicles for 100 sec of simulation. How can I do that?

Comment: You should have a look at the [documentation](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Trip#randomTrips.py). `-e` defines the end time.

Comment: @JulianHeinovski Thank you. I overlooked at Arrival rate.

Comment: @JulianHeinovski I am still not able to get my intended requirement. -e defines end time but I need say 1200 sec of simulation with just 100 vehicles and each vehicle starts at 0 seconds.

Comment: Look at the example: To let `n` vehicles depart between times `t0` and `t1` set the options `-b t0 -e t1 -p ((t1 - t0) / n)`. More control you cannot achieve by using `randomTrips.py`. Then you need to create a routes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer this (mainly rephrasing what Julian Heinovski said in the comments)

```
randomTrips.py -n net.net.xml -o passenger.trips.xml -e 100
```

will generate 100 trips. If you want to make sure all of them are possible (connected in the network) you can add `--validate` but this will remove invalid trips (and you may end up with less than 100). You can simply play around with the number then.

To let all of them start at second 0 you can edit the trips file using a regular expression replacement, replacing all departure times with 0s. On *nix the following will probably do:

```
sed -i 's/depart="[0-9]*/depart="0/' passenger.trips.xml
```

Now you can start sumo for the period of your choice

```
sumo -n net.net.xml -r passenger.trips.xml -e 1200
```

Comment: Hi, Michael thank you for your comment but I am already doing same. But still to run 100 vehicles for 1200 sec of simulation there is no option to have a longer path for vehicles, almost all vehicles exit the simulation half way of the simulation. I am not able to find a workaround for this.

Comment: Did you try `--min-distance` with a large value for randomTrips.py?

Comment: I have tried it. Even for 2km distance, I get `no trips found after 100 tries`.

Answer (score 0):

Number of vehicles randomly distributed over specified period of time can be generated using --begin, --end and --period options.

For example to generate 1200 vehicles for 100 sec of simulation, following command can be used:

```
python randomTrips.py -n net.net.xml -r net.rou.xml -o net.trip.xml --begin=0 --end=100 --period=0.083333
```

In short,

```
number of generated vehicles = (end - begin) / period
```